# Cannot start Glassfish after install, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, glassfish

I am trying to install Glassfish 5.1 on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS box, but I get the following error when starting the service:

```
oct 28 00:47:13 Valhalla sudo[4132]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
oct 28 00:47:13 Valhalla systemd[1]: Starting GlassFish Server v5.0...
-- Subject: Unit glassfish.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit glassfish.service has begun starting up.
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla asadmin[4135]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla asadmin[4135]:         at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.initializeServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:152)
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla asadmin[4135]:         at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:144)
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla asadmin[4135]:         at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:218)
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla asadmin[4135]:         at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:224)
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla asadmin[4135]:         at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceLocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:88)
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla asadmin[4135]:         at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getServiceLocator(CLIContainer.java:217)
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla asadmin[4135]:         at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getLocalCommand(CLIContainer.java:255)
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla asadmin[4135]:         at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getCommand(CLICommand.java:231)
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla asadmin[4135]:         at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:371)
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla asadmin[4135]:         at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:306)
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla asadmin[4135]:         at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:57)
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla systemd[1]: glassfish.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla systemd[1]: glassfish.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
oct 28 00:47:15 Valhalla systemd[1]: Failed to start GlassFish Server v5.0.
```

The result of `sudo java -version` is as follows:

```
openjdk 11.0.9 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9+11-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9+11-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I am following the install instructions found [here](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-glassfish-on-ubuntu-18-04/) (Only instruction not followed was the installation of Java 8, not sure if Glassfish doesn't play nice with other versions).

I am also running Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) on port 80.

Thank you in advance for your insights and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most probably due to your java version, you are using OpenJDK while Glassfish needs Oracle JDK .

> Eclipse GlassFish Server Release 5.1 requires Oracle JDK 8 Update 144
> or later.

Official [doc](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/glassfish/docs/5.1.0/release-notes/release-notes.html#abpak).

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you are using OpenJDK or Oracle JDK, just that you are on JDK 8 for Glassfish 5.